# Game about eating fast food

Tags: java, game

This is a very simple text-based "game" I made in Java. The whole idea is to repeatedly type "eat/sip _____" until you eat all the food and win.

(Pertaining to skill level) I have been programming in Java for a little over two years, in high school. I feel I can be considered a beginner, but not quite enough to warrant the use of the `beginner` tag.

This is my code, please let me know if you have any suggestions, or need clarification.

**EatFood.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class EatFood {
    private final String TITLE = "Eat Food";

    private int minFood = 3;
    private int maxFood = 5;

    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Random rand = new Random();

    private ArrayList<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();

    public EatFood() {
        play();
    }

    public void play() {
        setupFood();
        System.out.println("**********" + TITLE + "**********");

        System.out.print("Press Enter to continue...");
        in.nextLine();

        do {
            String input;
            System.out.println("");

            displayFood();

            System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
            System.out.print(">");
            input = in.nextLine();

            boolean isValid = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++) {
                if (foods.get(i).isValidInput(input)) {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }

            if (isValid) {
                int whichFood = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++) {
                    if (input.contains(foods.get(i).getName())) {
                        whichFood = i;
                    }
                }

                foods.get(whichFood).doBehavior(input);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not valid input.");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++)
                if (foods.get(i).isFinished())
                    foods.remove(i);

        } while (foods.size() > 0);

        System.out.println("\nYou win!\n");
    }

    public void displayFood() {
        String output = "In front of you there " + foods.get(0).getBeginList() + " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++) {
            output += foods.get(i).display();

            output += i != foods.size() - 1 ? ", " : "";
            output += i == foods.size() - 2 ? "and " : "";
        }

        System.out.println(output + ".");
    }

    public void setupFood() {
        foods.add(new Burger("burger", 12, 18, "is", "a", rand));
        foods.add(new CheeseBurger("cheeseburger", 12, 18, "is", "a", rand));
        foods.add(new ChickenNuggets("chicken nuggets", 12, 18, "are", "some", rand));
        foods.add(new Soda("soda", 12, 18, "is", "a", rand));
        foods.add(new Fries("fries", 12, 18, "are", "some", rand));

        selectFoods();
    }

    public void selectFoods() {
        int numFoods = rand.nextInt(maxFood - minFood) + minFood;
        int foodRemoved = maxFood - numFoods;

        for (int i = 0; i < foodRemoved; i++) {
            foods.remove(rand.nextInt(foods.size()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EatFood();
    }
}
```

**Food.java**

```
abstract class Food {
    private String name;
    private int capacity, minCap, maxCap;
    private String beginList, describeAmount;
    private boolean finished = false;
    private Random rand;
    protected Behavior behavior;

    public Food(String name, int minCap, int maxCap, String beginList, String describeAmount, Random rand) {
        this.name = name;
        this.minCap = minCap;
        this.maxCap = maxCap;
        this.beginList = beginList;
        this.describeAmount = describeAmount;
        this.rand = rand;

        defineCapacity();
    }

    //getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBeginList() {
        return beginList;
    }


    //booleans
    public boolean isFinished() {
        return finished;
    }

    public boolean isValidInput(String input) {
        return input.contains(name) && behavior.containsAction(input);
    }


    //functionality
    public String display() {
        return describeAmount + " " + name;
    }

    public void doBehavior(String input) {
        if (finished) return;

        String action = behavior.getContainedAction(input);

        if (behavior.hasAction(action))
            capacity = capacity - behavior.getBehavior(action);

        if (capacity <= 0) {
            finished = true;
            System.out.println("Finished" + " " + describeAmount + " " + name);
        }
    }

    private void defineCapacity() {
        capacity = rand.nextInt(maxCap - minCap) + minCap;
    }
}
```

**Burger.java**

```
class Burger extends Food {
    String[] actions = {"eat", "bite", "devour", "inhale"};
    int[] behaviors = {2, 1, 4, 6};

    public Burger(String name, int minCap, int maxCap, String beginList, String describeAmount, Random rand) {
        super(name, minCap, maxCap, beginList, describeAmount, rand);

        behavior = new Behavior(actions, behaviors);
    }
}
```

**CheeseBurger**

```
class CheeseBurger extends Food {
    String[] actions = {"eat", "bite", "devour", "inhale"};
    int[] behaviors = {2, 1, 4, 7};

    public CheeseBurger(String name, int minCap, int maxCap, String beginList, String describeAmount, Random rand) {
        super(name, minCap, maxCap, beginList, describeAmount, rand);

        behavior = new Behavior(actions, behaviors);
    }
}
```

**ChickenNuggets.java**

```
class ChickenNuggets extends Food {
    String[] actions = {"eat", "devour", "inhale"};
    int[] behaviors = {1, 3, 5};

    public ChickenNuggets(String name, int minCap, int maxCap, String beginList, String describeAmount, Random rand) {
        super(name, minCap, maxCap, beginList, describeAmount, rand);

        behavior = new Behavior(actions, behaviors);
    }
}
```

**Soda.java**

```
class Soda extends Food {
    String[] actions = {"sip", "drink", "chug"};
    int[] behaviors = {2, 1, 5};

    public Soda(String name, int minCap, int maxCap, String beginList, String describeAmount, Random rand) {
        super(name, minCap, maxCap, beginList, describeAmount, rand);

        behavior = new Behavior(actions, behaviors);
    }
}
```

**Fries.java**

```
class Fries extends Food {
    String[] actions = {"eat", "munch", "devour", "inhale"};
    int[] behaviors = {2, 1, 5, 7};

    public Fries(String name, int minCap, int maxCap, String beginList, String describeAmount, Random rand) {
        super(name, minCap, maxCap, beginList, describeAmount, rand);

        behavior = new Behavior(actions, behaviors);
    }
}
```

**Behavior.java**

```
class Behavior {
    String[] actions;
    int[] behaviors;

    public Behavior(String[] actions, int[] behaviors) {
        this.actions = actions;
        this.behaviors = behaviors;
    }

    public String getContainedAction(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
            if (input.contains(actions[i]))
                return actions[i];

        return "";
    }

    public int getBehavior(String action) {
        return behaviors[getIndex(action)];
    }

    public int getIndex(String action) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
            if (action.equals(actions[i]))
                return i;

        return -1;
    }

    public boolean hasAction(String action) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
            if (action.equals(actions[i]))
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public boolean containsAction(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
            if (input.contains(actions[i]))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Structure**

It seems that there are a limited number of actions. I would suggest using an enum instead of a string.

How you build your food isn't very clear when seeing a constructor call:

> foods.add(new Soda("soda", 12, 18, "is", "a", rand));

The first is obviously the name, but after that, I would need to look at the documentation or code of the food constructor.

There are multiple solutions for this. You could use the builder pattern, you could combine parameters into objects (min and max cap for example might be a range, and beginList and describeAmount also seem to belong together), or you could just reduce the number of parameters by removing unnecessary ones (is there really a reason to pass rand in? Should the name of a burger ever not be burger?).

Is there a reason that the Food class doesn't build the behavior? It seems to be an action that is common to all foods.

Your play method is a bit long for my taste, and does a bit too much. I would move all the printing into their own methods (like displayIntro, displayWin, displayInput). The logic could likely also be improved. Is there a need to check foods for removal for invalid input? It doesn't seem like it, so your code may look like this:

```
    do {
        displayFood();

        displayInput();
        String input = getInput();

        if (!isValidInput(input)) {
            displayInvalidInput();
            continue;
        }

        int whichFood = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++) {
             if (input.contains(foods.get(i).getName())) {
                whichFood = i;
            }
        }

        foods.get(whichFood).doBehavior(input);

        for (int i = 0; i < foods.size(); i++)
            if (foods.get(i).isFinished())
                foods.remove(i);

    } while (foods.size() > 0);
```

I would move the invalid input loop into the getInput method itself though.

**Documentation**

You should definitely add JavaDoc comments to your public methods. It's not really clear to me what `behaviors` are, what `minCap` and `maxCap` are refering to, what a `beginList` is, and so on. Better variable names and structure may help here, but in my opinion documentation is a must.

**Misc**

- You have some style and other minor violations in your code, you can use any IDE or lint tool to find and fix them. Example would be importing `*`, not making your fields private/public, or not having curly braces around one-line statements.

Comment: "*Should the name of a burger ever not be burger?*" - Also, you know what they call a Quarter Pounder with   Cheese in Paris?